# Destructuring Objects Passed as Ember Action Arguments

Tags: ember.js, action

Official [Ember Guide about actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/) emphasizes that destructuring objects passed as action arguments is possible with the use of `value` named parameter within the action helper. My problem is that this scenario works only for the first argument but fails for the remaining arguments of the action.

Please see the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ca6a57b63a1865f80e173438afd293f2) I have prepared to illustrate the case. In this simple twiddle, `my-component` triggers an action after button click and the `application` controller handles the action. As can be seen within `application.hbs` I declared the action as `(action 'actionHandler' value='name')`; this means I want the name fields of the action arguments to be sent to the action handler within `application.js`. However as can be seen from the alerts displayed; the `value` parameter is working for the first argument of the action (`john` is displayed as expected); but fails for the second argument (`jack` is not retrieved as the second argument of the action handler; but the whole object retrieved).

My question is; is there a way to destructure the arguments after the first one? If it is possible, can I vary the properties to be extracted among argument, i.e. `name` of first argument, `id` of second argument and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is No.Like you shown in twiddle, You can't destructure the arguments after the first one. 
I used this feature mostly when I want to take `value` from first argument `event` by saying `value=target.value`. In this, destructure will be applied for first argument alone, along with we can send many no of arguments which will not be destructured.

Comment: I believe someone will come up with exact source code for why we can't?

Comment: I found this from [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/516e93c7745c59748fc237b791b18c908c4b14f7/packages/ember-glimmer/lib/helpers/action.js#L329). It is only processing the first one.